# When downloading (using scp?) a file via symbolic link is it possible to save it under the original filename?

Tags: linux, symlink, scp

On a server, the directory structure is already organized like this.  (For sake of argument, I can't change it.  I can only figure out a way to make it more useful to me.)

```
/work/product/versions/app-0.98
/work/product/versions/app-1.0
/work/product/versions/app-1.1
/work/product/versions/app-1.2
```

Inside each directory are several files, for example:

```
/work/product/versions/app-0.98/app-0.98.1234
/work/product/versions/app-0.98/app-0.98.1235
/work/product/versions/app-0.98/app-0.98.1236
/work/product/versions/app-0.98/app-0.98.1237
```

When I get a version I like, I want to symlink it to `release`, like:

```
ln -s /work/product/versions/app-0.98/app-0.98.1237 /work/product/versions/app-0.98/release
```

This way, I can always download my validated release by asking for the `release` file.  I download them like this:

```
scp me@host01:/work/product/versions/app-0.98/release .
```

On my local filesystem, I am left with a file named "release".

```
me@host01:/home/me# ls -al
total 528948
drwxr-xr-x 2 me me      4096 Feb  6 12:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 me me      4096 Feb  2 13:03 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 me me 541627065 Feb  6 12:25 release
```

I'd like the file to be named the same as the original file, `app-0.98.1237`.  Is there something I can change on my server or in my `scp` call to save the file using the original file name?

I'm on a variety of OSes, primarily Linux - Debian and CentOS distros.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can come off the top of my head is a two-step process that uses `rsync` rather than naked `scp` (rsync can use `scp` as its back-end):

First, copy the link itself:

```
rsync -a username@host:/path/to/release .
```

Then, copy whatever the target might be:

```
rsync -za username@host:"$(basename "$(readlink release)")" .
```

You will then end up with this:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
drwxrwxr-x  3 username  groupname  96 Feb  6 11:10 1.02
lrwxrwxrwx  1 username  groupname   4 Feb  6 11:09 release -> 1.02
```